# Unable to concatenate strings in Python2.7

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate two strings in my function. I tried all concatenation, but those two strings just don't concatenate one after another, instead, shorter strings B(length = s) substitute the first s units of longer string A.

I read some data from input file, and store third line whose content is "00001M035NNYY1111111" into a variable called applicant:

```
data = open("input.txt").read().split('\n')

applicant = str(data[2])
```

I want to add an integer 8 at the end of `applicant`, so the new `applicant` will be "00001M035NNYY11111118". I tried `applicant += str(8)` and `"".join((applicant, str(8)))` and other concatenation methods, but all of them only give me "80001M035NNYY1111111"... Does anyone know why this happened and how am I suppose to do to get my intended result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have Windows line endings in your file: `\r\n`. By splitting on `\n`, you leave the `\r`, which returns to the beginning of the line. You can trim it manually:

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
    data = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
```

Comment: Yes! the problem IS windows line endings, thank you! I used `applicant = applicant[:20] + str(8)` to solve the problem, but your solution is better!

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> data = open("input.txt").read().split("\n")
>>> applicant = data[2] + str(8)
>>> print applicant
00001M035NNYY11111118
>>>
```

There is probably something wrong with your text file if this does not work.